# Accommodation arrangements when you only have one key

Tags: accommodation

My friend and I have been traveling in the past and will be traveling soon again. For economy reasons we will be sharing accommodations. We usually go for AirBnB. The problem with renting a private room in a place (or usually also when having the entire place to ourselves) is that there's only one key to be had. Our sleep rhythms and daily routines are so different that it's becoming an obstacle.

Is there a smart way to cope with just one key between two people? It seems to be often that it cannot be left in a lockbox outside because you need it inside the house or on your way to the apartment.

Comment: I won't be checking on this question until tomorrow as I'm traveling for holidays. Merry Christmas!

Comment: Not being familiar with AirBnB I wonder if the number of keys is something that is indicated on the pages for the accommodation. Can you select on the number of keys available?

Comment: I’m an Airbnb host and I always ask my guests whether they would like more than one key. I recommend you message the host (before booking would be best) to request two keys, or you could ask on arrival if the host is there to check you in. It really shouldn’t be a problem - hosts usually have a ‘lost key’ policy stating you’d need to cover replacement lock costs if you don’t return keys.